# Why UITableView calls UIScrollView's delegate methods?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uitableview

I have an application, in which I have a `UITableView` inside a `UIView`, which is again inside a `UIScrollView`, so the hierarchy becomes like this:

`UIScrollView` -> `UIView` -> `UITableView`

The data inside my `UITableView` is filled properly.

Now, my problem is that, When I scroll my `UITableView`, the `UIScrollView's` delegate method `scrollViewDidEndDecelerating:` and `scrollViewDidEndDragging::` gets called.

I don't want this behavior, what should I do to stop this behavior?

Any one please Help,
Thank in advance!!!

Comment: If I understand you correctly you have 2 scroll views as UITable already sits on a scroll view. This could be causing the problem.

Comment: No, I have kept [parentScroll setScrollEnabled:NO]... So that is not the problem...

Comment: OK In that case I see why this would be confusing , let me have a think

Comment: +1 looking for same, But tag property is not working for me, I have subclass scroll view and it always call scrollview's method when i scroll table view.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

UITableViewDelegate extends UIScrollViewDelegate. Hence the calling of the delegate methods.

To stop this you can set `tableView.tag = 1000;` when you alloc the tableView and in the UIScrollViewDelegate methods ( `scrollViewDidEndDecelerating: and scrollViewDidEndDragging::` )add this at the very begining:

```
if(scrollView.tag == 1000)
    return;
```

Comment: ...or keep a pointer to the table view as an ivar and compare to that.

Comment: true. I use tags in order to minimize the use of pointers. Not that I'm afraid of them , but IMO making use of autorelease and tags makes the code less vulnerable to memory leaks.

Comment: I use pointer because of an irrational fear that the tags might en up not being unique! Dumb in this case, I know...

Answer (score 3):

Because UITableView inherits from UIScrollView. So it shows all the properties and behaviours of UIScrollView. If you dont want this then please do one thing.

Assuming you have another scrollview in your page.

in the `viewDidLoad` or from the `XIB` (if you have your tableview in the XIB), set a tag for your tableview.

in code,

```
self.objYourTableView.tag = 101;
```

then in the scroll view delegate

```
- (void)scrollViewWillBeginDecelerating:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
  {
       if(!(scrollView.tag == 101))
       {
          // Go for your code to run.
       }
  }
```

So that your code will skip if it called by the table view. Other cases it works perfect. Hope this will help you.

Comment: `Because UITableView inherits from UIScrollView` . No. It's because `Because UITableViewDelegate inherits from UIScrollViewDelegate`.